# How to apply TAP on a "partially" async method?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I'll start by explaining what I mean with "partially" async:
I have a method `A` that does a bunch of things. One of these things is calling another method `B` that is (fully) async. As a result, I let `A` return the Task from `B` and do the rest of `A` in a continuation.

Now `A` is also an async method, however everything before `B` is called is still synchronous. According to [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) an async method should only do minimal synchronous work before returning the Task.

What should I do in this situation?

These are the options I have considered:

1. Let whatever code calls `A` wrap `A` in a Task.

   1. Just don't postfix `A` with "Async".
   2. Also don't do `B` asynchronous either.
2. Make `A` completely asynchronous.

   1. Postfix `A` with Async and wrap the whole `A` in a Task.
   2. Don't do `B` asynchronous anymore because `A`'s Task already wraps it.

### Code:

Base

```
public Task BAsync() {
    return Task.Run(B);
}

private void B() { /* stuff.. */ }
```

Option 1.1

```
public async Task A() {
    // stuff..
    await BAsync();
    // stuff..
}
```

Option 1.2

```
public void A() {
    // stuff..
    B();
    // stuff..
}
```

Option 2.1

```
public Task AAsync() {
    return Task.Run(A);
}

private async Task A() {
    // stuff..
    await BAsync();
    // stuff..
}
```

Option 2.2

```
public Task AAsync() {
    return Task.Run(A);
}

private void A() {
    // stuff..
    B();
    // stuff..
}
```

Comment: What behaviour does the *caller* want?

Comment: @JonSkeet A non-blocking UI. Which I'm also writing (i.e. I could wrap everything in a Task from there).

Comment: Well if your caller is a UI, then presumably you don't want the work done before the call to B to be in the same thread, do you?

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, all of the options I considered would cause that work to be done on another thread, right? Option 1 and 1.1 put the responsibility of wrapping it in a Task at the caller. In this case the UI.

Comment: What makes `A` and `B` different? Why do you consider them separately instead of treating both the same?

Comment: @svick `B` is a method I made before for another purpose for which it was required to be asynchronous. `B` is reused in `A`.

Comment: More specifically, `B` is a write operation on a COM object that fires an OnWriteComplete event when the write is successful. I wrapped this in a Task. I generalized the question such that `B` can be turned synchronous. Which in my specific case would require `B` to block until the OnWriteComplete occurs. That would probably not be the best solution, though, hence the generalization.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels That makes more sense. What confused me is your code for `BAsync()` (which just calls `Task.Run(B)`).

Comment: @svick I guess I can generalize the question even further: Should I only think about making long running operations Async at the top level (e.g. `A` or the `UIThread`) or is it also OK to make a lot of sub methods that do bits that are long running Async (e.g. `B`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic principle is that synchronous methods should be synchronous and asynchronous methods should be asynchronous, there shouldn't be anything between that.

So I think that option 2.1 is best here.

One exception could be if you had something like performance critical ASP.NET application. You don't have a UI thread there (that you want to keep free as much as possible). And you might care about the performance penalty of running all the code asynchronously. In that case, I think option 1 would be appropriate (but the behavior should also be documented).